# Why is JOOQ's fetchOneInto(Pojo.class) setting only id field, and others to null?

Tags: java, jooq

I'm using a `users` table, defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique user id.',
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'username(unique identifier for each user.)',
  `password` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'password encrypted with salt.',
  `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'phone number(phone number should be unique for each user.)',
  `email` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'e-mail(e-mail should be unique for each user.)',
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','LOCKED','DELETED') NOT NULL COMMENT 'user account status.',
  `isDeleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'boolean flag deleting whether the user is deleted or not.',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Date and time of user creation.',
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Date and time when the user was last updated.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`,`phone`,`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Also, a custom `User` POJO, that looks something like:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String userPhone;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

// Getters and Setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Now, when I simply `fetch()` the record, it works fine:

```
UsersRecord user = new DSLContextFactory("demo").getDSLContext()
                .selectFrom(USERS)
                .where(USERS.USERNAME.eq("james"))
                .fetchOne();
        System.out.println(user);
```

The snippet above returns[image]

But, if I try `fetchOneInto(User.class)`, it only lodges the id field to `User`:

```
User user = new DSLContextFactory("demo").getDSLContext()
                .selectFrom(USERS)
                .where(USERS.USERNAME.eq("james"))
                .fetchOneInto(User.class);
        System.out.println(user);
```

Now, the above snippet returns this:

```
[User{id=3, userName='null', userPhone='null', userEmail='null'}]
```

I have not the slightest clue what's going on here. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using JOOQ `3.15.0`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the culprit here was the usage of `jakarta.persistence-api`. Switching to `javax.persistence-api` made things all fine and dandy.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9641